# Interactive rm command

Tags: rm

When I remove some directories, I often forgot their structure and consequently I don't add the `-rf` flags when needed. When this happens, `rm` just returns an error and reminds me that I am trying to delete a directory.

Is there a program that would instead ask whether I want to remove the directory, or remove with root privileges?

```
rm foo
foo is directory, Want to remove it [Y/n]
foo/bar owned by root, Want to increase privileges [Y/n]
```

Comment: It doesn't matter who owns `foo/bar` (as long as `foo` doesn't have the `t` bit). To be able to delete it, you only need write access to `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. What you're looking for is the advanced behaviour of a script, which you won't find in UNIX commands as they are designed to do one simple thing and do it well.

You could write a script to automatically tell a file from a directory and hence use the appropriate `rm` or `rmdir` (first requirement), but you'd need to run the script with root privileges for it to be able to remove root-owned files (second requirement). In fact, you can't increase privileges in a root script.

Comment: One could use `sudo` (or equivalent) in the script (or better, function) to escalate privileges. The issue is dealing with command line flags and command line flag-like file names. You would have to do full processing of the command line to be able to correctly pass on any user-supplied flags to the real `rm`.

Comment: I'm not talking about Unix commands. I'm talking about programs in general. I could easily write one myself even in `sh`. I just don't want to do that, if someone else already done that.